# unable to activate again my product in plone

Tags: plone, diazo

I deactivated accidentally my customized product from the plone control panel, and now I'm unable to activate it again, as i get the error page saying:

AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getId'",) (Also, the following error occurred while attempting to render the standard error message, please see the event log for full details: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getId')

I neither can access the portal quickinstaller tool as the index.html page from my diazo theme included into that product appears (even if I disable the theme or deactivate diazo).

I also tried to lunch again the buildout, but nothing changes

Comment: In addition I can say I have two sites on that plone node; on the first I can access the quickinstaller and activate the product, on the second one (with diazo installed) I can't

Comment: ok now I was able to use the quickinstaller dropping there the theme, as I added the rule:

Comment: <notheme if-path="portal_quickinstaller/manage_installProductsForm"/>, but my diazo theme disappeared now

Comment: ok, when I added the rule

<notheme if-path="portal_quickinstaller/manage_installProductsForm"/>

I was able to use the quickinstaller again and restore things; the problem is that for several tools in the ZMI the url always appears to be /manage, while sometimes is different and there are redirection; anyway there's something I still don't understand as according to diazo documentation, the rule <notheme if-path="manage"/> should prevent me to see the theme everywhere in the ZMI, but instead you have to apply the notheme for each url tool (at least this is what I am experiencing)

Comment: It you want help, you're going to have to post complete tracebacks. Also, diazo rule files.

Comment: Please read http://plone.org/documentation/kb/diagnosing-third-party-product-installation-problems to provide meaningful error information

Answer (score 0):

Not related to your original question, but you also mentioned problems accessing your site because of Diazo rules.  You can configure Diazo not to theme the site when visiting from certain host names or IP addresses.  Go to Site Setup->Diazo->Advanced Settings->Unthemed Hostnames and add host names or IP addresses that you don't want themed.